# response 404 on using requests for scraping postal data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

for education purposes I want to scrap the population of Germany per pin code. This information is available at https://postal-codes.cybo.com/germany/

I tried to run web scraping tools such as requests and some others which I found in stackoverflow.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                            
headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://postal-codes.cybo.com/germany'
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.title.text)
print(r.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.title.text)
```

can someone guide me on how to approach this issue? Is there any other way I ca get the population of Germany per post /pin code.

Thank you in advance!!

https://postal-codes.cybo.com/germany/#listcodes

basically I want to scrap this data, postal code, city, population area - if we open individual postal code then we can also wee male/female polulation as well

[image: basically I want to scrap this data, postal code, city, population area - if we open individual postal code then we can also wee male/female polulation as well]

Comment: The site is `cloudflare` protected - *Cloudflare is a global network designed to make everything you connect to the Internet secure, private, fast, and reliable. Secure your websites, APIs, and Internet applications. Protect corporate networks, employees, and devices. Write and deploy code that runs on the network edge.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site's protected by Cloudflare but it's possible to bypass the challenge with the `cloudscraper` module.

Here's how:

```py
import cloudscraper
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate


scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()

source_html = (
    BeautifulSoup(
        scraper.get("https://postal-codes.cybo.com/germany/?p=1").text,
        "lxml",
    ).select("table.paleblue")[-1]
)

columns = [
    "Postal Code", "City", "Administrative Region", "Population", "Area",
]
df = pd.concat(pd.read_html(str(source_html).replace("%", "")))
df = df.reindex(columns=columns)
df.drop(df.tail(1).index, inplace=True)
print(tabulate(df, headers="keys", tablefmt="psql", showindex=False))
df.to_csv("postal_codes_germany.csv", index=False)
```

This should print (and also dump the data from the first page to a `.csv` file):

```json
+---------------+--------------------+-------------------------+--------------+-----------+
|   Postal Code | City               | Administrative Region   | Population   | Area      |
|---------------+--------------------+-------------------------+--------------+-----------|
|         01067 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | 26664        | 6.7 km²   |
|         01069 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | 24682        | 5.3 km²   |
|         01097 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | 16468        | 3.417 km² |
|         01099 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | 26147        | 52.8 km²  |
|         01108 | —                  | Saxony                  | —            | —         |
|         01109 | Klotzsche          | Saxony                  | 33677        | 27.2 km²  |
|         01127 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | 12998        | 2.827 km² |
|         01129 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | 17585        | 8.3 km²   |
|         01139 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | 29363        | 8.5 km²   |
|         01156 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | —            | —         |
|         01157 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | 24767        | 8.5 km²   |
|         01159 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | 27573        | 5.7 km²   |
|         01169 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | 15136        | 5.1 km²   |
|         01187 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | 14150        | 5 km²     |
|         01189 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | 12040        | 5.3 km²   |
|         01217 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | 12810        | 5.2 km²   |
|         01219 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | 20713        | 7.5 km²   |
|         01237 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | 17916        | 4.314 km² |
|         01239 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | 11957        | 3.634 km² |
|         01257 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | 24753        | 8.4 km²   |
|         01259 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | 18304        | 10.4 km²  |
|         01277 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | 20606        | 4.616 km² |
|         01279 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | 12092        | 5.4 km²   |
|         01307 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | 14597        | 3.381 km² |
|         01309 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | 18589        | 4.863 km² |
|         01324 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | 7757         | 9.1 km²   |
|         01326 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | 10859        | 15.3 km²  |
|         01328 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | —            | —         |
|         01445 | Radebeul           | Saxony                  | 32518        | 26 km²    |
|         01454 | Wachau, Saxony     | Saxony                  | 20523        | 59 km²    |
|         01458 | Ottendorf-Okrilla  | Saxony                  | 10242        | 36 km²    |
|         01462 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | 26184        | 31.1 km²  |
|         01465 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | 4274         | 12.1 km²  |
|         01468 | Moritzburg, Saxony | Saxony                  | 10414        | 68 km²    |
|         01471 | Radeburg           | Saxony                  | 5126         | 33.1 km²  |
|         01474 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | 15710        | 40.9 km²  |
|         01477 | Arnsdorf           | Saxony                  | 4503         | 35.6 km²  |
|         01478 | Dresden            | Saxony                  | 9106         | 16.3 km²  |
|         01558 | Großenhain         | Saxony                  | 12856        | 37.9 km²  |
|         01561 | Schönfeld, Saxony  | Saxony                  | 21540        | 418.4 km² |
|         01587 | Riesa              | Saxony                  | 11165        | 7.5 km²   |
|         01589 | Riesa              | Saxony                  | 7550         | 15.3 km²  |
|         01591 | Riesa              | Saxony                  | 11368        | 16.9 km²  |
|         01594 | —                  | Saxony                  | 7355         | 86.5 km²  |
|         01609 | Nauwalde           | Saxony                  | 12121        | 85.1 km²  |
|         01612 | Nünchritz          | Saxony                  | 7115         | 45 km²    |
|         01616 | Strehla            | Saxony                  | 3888         | 30.1 km²  |
|         01619 | Zeithain           | Saxony                  | 5680         | 81.5 km²  |
|         01623 | Lommatzsch         | Saxony                  | 9148         | 139.8 km² |
|         01640 | Coswig, Saxony     | Saxony                  | 21213        | 26.1 km²  |
+---------------+--------------------+-------------------------+--------------+-----------+
```

Comment: That's awesome but I received an error while running this code block.  ```
ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

cloudscraper.exceptions.CloudflareChallengeError: Detected a Cloudflare version 2 Captcha challenge, This feature is not available in the opensource (free) version.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError: 'CloudflareChallengeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'
```

Comment: Hmm... make sure you have the right module - [cloudscraper](https://github.com/VeNoMouS/cloudscraper).

Comment: tried everything possible but somehow it didn't work. In any case, Thanks for sharing the solution :)